# Calculation on return cashback

Tags: java

I am a student who has just started getting touched with coding. I was trying to code a cashback calculation, but I got the wrong output. The calculation is based on which category user chooses; petrol, groceries, ewallet, etc. Once I get the categories, the list will get the amount based on the categories and calculate with the bonus cash back and cash back on eligible spend. If the amount calculated is more than or equal to 15, it will return 15.

The cashback calculation code:

```
private void function1() {
  double amountGet, cashback = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< dataList.size(); i++) {
    if(dataList.get(i).getCategory() == "Petrol Spend") {
      amountGet = dataList.get(i).getAmount();
      cashback = amountGet * 0.08;
      if(cashback > 15) {
        cashback = 15.00;
      }
    } else if(dataList.get(i).getCategory() == "Groceries Spend") {
      amountGet = dataList.get(i).getAmount();
      cashback = (amountGet * 0.078) + (amountGet * 0.002);
      if(cashback > 15) {
        cashback = 15.00;
      }
    } else if(dataList.get(i).getCategory() == "eWallet Transaction") {
      amountGet = dataList.get(i).getAmount();
      cashback = (amountGet * 0.078) + (amountGet*0.002);
      if(cashback > 15) {
        cashback = 15.00;
      }
    } else if (dataList.get(i).getCategory() == "Other Eligible Spend") {
      amountGet = dataList.get(i).getAmount();
      cashback = amountGet * 0.002;
      if (cashback > 15) {
        cashback = 15.00;
      }
    }
    list.add(cashback);
  }
}
```

This button for invoking the calculation code:

```
 calculateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      calculateCashBack();
    }
 });
    
 private void calculateCashBack() {
   if (totalAmount >=2000) {
     function1();
   } else {
     function2();
   }
    
   for (int i =0; i< list.size(); i++) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Item with ID :" + dataList.get(i).getId() + "with the amount of : RM" + dataList.get(i).getAmount() + "get Cashback of : RM" + list.get(i));
   }
 }
```

This is my output:

[image]

I would very much appreciate any the help from the experts...

Comment: Are you positive that totalAmount >= 2000? Because if not then the function2() gets called and you didn't post source for that function

Comment: Start with: not using == to compare strings. Use the `equals()` method instead.

Comment: Also note that this code looks like 2010 from a style point of view. That is really not how you iterate a list these days.

Answer (score 0):

As @GhostCat said, you should use String.equals() to compare strings. Here is an example of a more optimize, and prettier, code

```java
// Init static values here
private Map<String, Float> cashbacks;  // HashMap linking Category to dedicated cashback
static {
  cashbacks = new HashMap<>();
  cashbacks.put("Petrol Spend", 0.08f);
  cashbacks.put("Groceries Spend", 0.08f);
  cashbacks.put("eWallet Transaction", 0.08f);
  cashbacks.put("Other Eligible Spend", 0.002f);
}

/**
 * Compute cashbacks for a list of data
 * @param dataList List of data
 * @return List of corresponding cashbacks
 */
private List<Float> function1(List<Data> dataList) {
  List<Float> results = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Data data : dataList) {
    // Find the category in the map 
    Float cash = cashbacks.get(data.category());
    if (cash ==  null) {
        cash = 0f; // default value here if no category found
    }
    // compute the total amount and limit the result to 15
    results.add(Math.min(data.getAmount() * cash, 15));
  }
  return  results;
}
```

How to use it? Simple:

```java
private void calculateCashBack() {
   List<Float> cashbacks;
   if (totalAmount >=2000) {
     cashbacks = function1(dataList);
   } else {
     cashbacks = function2(dataList);  // I suppose that this function has the same signature
   }
    
   for (int i =0; i< cashbacks.size(); i++) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Item with ID :" + dataList.get(i).getId() + " with the amount of : RM " + dataList.get(i).getAmount() + " get Cashback of : RM " + cashbacks.get(i));
   }
 }
```